# The 'BCRY Exporter' export button doesn't show up

Tags: export, add-on

I tried everything but BCRY Exporter 5 or any other version does NOT WORK! It does nothing and the button doesn't show up to export or use. The BCRY button doesn't exist and sadly I'm running out of time. This is my last resort to get some answers or I must, even though I don't want to, move on from this.

Comment: Hi. Please don't capitalise the first letter of every word. It took a while to correct.

Comment: Hello and welcome to Blender SE! BCRY Exporter 5.1 was last updated in December 2017. The last supported Blender version was 2.79 ([Download it here](https://download.blender.org/release/Blender2.79/)).

Comment: God Bless Ray Mairlot! :)

Comment: Sorry thats just how i talk lol, didnt know you wold fix it xD

Comment: OMG Thanks So Much, Im srry its  how i show gratefullness, You saved my life! :D Thanks!

Comment: Thanks again guys, i appreciate all the guidance! srry about the caps lol